# Firefox reloads page, but no Location header sent or JS used

Tags: php, http, firefox

In one app, I have an administrative backend written in PHP, which allows to browse internal data structures or change settings.

One controller queries a DB backend checks against another reference DB using SOAP and returns a list of missing values. Takes a few seconds to complete.

The PHP code doesn't send a HTTP Location header, nor does the client-side kicks off JS code.

If I submit a request, the controller starts, finishes and **automatically (!) starts again**. The second start terminates normally - emits a report too. The **behaviour happens deterministic** each time I call the script.

After hours of debugging, I finally made the PHP code send a report back to me, which includes emitted HTML-Code. As a result, **I receive two reports**. But again, I receive two emails. The restart of the script happens instantly.

I know, this isn't much I can supply, but might this be some Firefox bug?

*Other browsers run the PHP script once and only once*.

**Update 2012-01-09**

The problem persists. Still, firefox reloads the page, no other browser does.

No method, especially tracing HTTP-request / -reply did show anything special.

Comment: Do you have code that you can post?  Also, is it live for others to test?  It's hard to troubleshoot something like this, as some of the variables at play could be your local settings on firefox, etc.

Comment: No, unfortunately not. Neither live, not postable. The module is company-internal. Too bad. Hm, Firefox setting. I shoud disable all plugins and try again. Thx!

Comment: Today, I reviewed the process usinng FF's Live Headers plugin. Result: Page reloads, but the app doesn't send a header, which may force the page to reload. Thus, I still wonder, why the page reloads.

Comment: I resign. All new debugging alternatives didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the "Live HTTP headers" Firefox plugin to monitor what's going on. The page is obviously loaded 2 times, this will help you determine how you end up with something like this.

Comment: Thx! I checked it with FireBug, but found nothing. Will try again. Furthermore, I should submit the request using terminal and grab all incoming data.

Comment: Live HTTP headers was helpful, but in fact didn't show anything new relative to FireBug. I saw the exact same header - not Location or such.

Comment: What happens if you disable Javascript?

Comment: Nothing. Even reloads, if I disable JavaScript. With XAMPP on my dev PC and with Apache on the Linux-based live host. Identical behavior.

Comment: I resign. This was the n-th effort to catch the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use a proxy to see how the traffic is different across browsers (I use http://www.fiddler2.com/ it's a Microsoft project but works with all browsers).

Comment: Fiddler is on my dev PC. If even this shows nothing, I'll give Etherreal a try.

Comment: Additionally, I'll enable my own class CStatementTracer, which dumps each executed PHP statement to a file. Let's see.

Comment: Today, I checked again. Disabled all plugins. Disabled JavaScript. Restarted Firefox. One URL entered manually make the request complete and automatically restart a new request. Firefox only.

Answer (score 0):

Same Problem here. I think i know whats causing the problem. I echo some debugging stuff before the DOCTYPE/HTML-Tag. And maybe FF thinks there is something wrong with the page, so it reloads it once more.

That sounds crazy, but if i don't echo anything before html it works fine.

Comment: Hm, sounds Interesting. I'll check on wednesday.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending the correct character set headers? If Firefox thinks it started decoding the page with the wrong character set, it will reload the page to fix it.

Comment: Yes, the app sends this header. By RELOAD, do you mean a full round-trip [http-request -> http-reply] reload? Hm, can't believe...

Comment: @SteAp I'm not exactly sure what Firefox's caching behaviour is, but I don't think it caches partial responses (which I guess this would be) unless you send suitable headers such as accept-range.